# Acessing struct members through a variable

Tags: c++, generics, struct

I'm trying to access different kind of structs that have changing attributes. This is one struct I'm trying to work with:

```
struct person {
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    int age;
};
```

I have a variable that contains "name" (the first attribute of the struct).

```
string n = "name";
```

Now if I want to access the name, it's not possible to do this:

```
person.n = "Same";
```

Is there a work around or some other way I could access struct members? I'm trying to work with different kind of structs and I have one config file where I enter the name of the members. But then I have the problem of not being able to acess the struct members if the name is saved in a variable.

Comment: No, that's not possible in C++. You have to do it manually `if (n == "name") person.name = "Same"; else if (n == "address") person.address = ...`

Comment: or you can setup a map that maps strings to pointers to member. But that wont help you with your original problem, because you still need to spell out the members name in code.

Comment: A possible improvement would be to store in the config file only the values, in the same order as the fields are given in the `struct`. So that you know the first is the name, the second is the address, the third is the age, and so on... It would avoid to have to manually check against the field name.

Answer (score 0):

A struct, also known as a class, is a type. You cannot access non static members of a type without creating an instance of a type.

For a simplified analogy, you cannot assign the `int` type:

```
int = 42; // wrong
```

Instead, you must create an instance of the type. You can assign that instance:

```
int i{};
i = 42; // ok
```

Similarly, you must create an instance of a class in order to access the non static members of that instance:

```
person.name = "Same"; // wrong

person p {};
p.name = "Same"; // ok
```